# The requested URL returned 403 in the KendoEditor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, http-status-code-403, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I Use KendoUi in ASP.NET MVC I Want Use Kendo.Editor() I Write ThisCode

```
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(m => m)
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 500px;height:300px" })
.Tools(tools => tools.InsertImage())
.ImageBrowser(imageBrowser => imageBrowser
                                .Image("~/Uploads/Images/{0}")    
                                .Read("Read", "ImageBrowser")
                                .Create("Create", "ImageBrowser")
                                .Destroy("Destroy", "ImageBrowser")
                                .Upload("Upload", "ImageBrowser")
                                .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "ImageBrowser"))
)
```

and ImageBrowser Controller

```
 public partial class ImageBrowserController : EditorImageBrowserController
    {
        private const string contentFolderRoot = "~/Uploads/";
        private const string prettyName = "Images/";
        private static readonly string[] foldersToCopy = new[] { "~/Uploads/shared/" };


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the base paths from which content will be served.
        /// </summary>
        public override string ContentPath
        {
            get
            {
                return CreateUserFolder();
            }
        }

        private string CreateUserFolder()
        {
            var virtualPath = Path.Combine(contentFolderRoot, prettyName);

            var path = Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                foreach (var sourceFolder in foldersToCopy)
                {
                    CopyFolder(Server.MapPath(sourceFolder), path);
                }
            }
            return virtualPath;
        }

        private void CopyFolder(string source, string destination)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
            }

            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(source))
            {
                var dest = Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(file));
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, dest);
            }

            foreach (var folder in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(source))
            {
                var dest = Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(folder));
                CopyFolder(folder, dest);
            }
        }
    }
```

when run this View Kendo.Editor Create fine. but when click in `InsertImage` Icon get `The requested URL returned 403` error

Edit01:

View Code like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.TenderContent)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 500px;height:300px" })

    .Tools(tools => tools.InsertImage())
    .ImageBrowser(imageBrowser => imageBrowser
                                    .Image("~/Uploads/Images/{0}")
                                    .Read("Read", "ImageBrowser")
                                    .Create("Create", "ImageBrowser")
                                    .Destroy("Destroy", "ImageBrowser")
                                    .Upload("Upload", "ImageBrowser")
                                    .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "ImageBrowser"))
                                )
```

Solution image:
[image]

please help me. thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `Clear()` before `InsertImage()` like below:

```
.Tools(tools => tools.Clear().InsertImage())
```

Also you need to make sure below path is correct, the `Uploads` folder is directly under your Project, it should be on the same level as `Content` folder.

```
"~/Uploads/Images/{0}"
```

Comment: no i get this error.An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Comment: You're passing a model to your `imagebrowser` view, can you show more code about where did you use that model?